# update nth line after search word is found

Tags: shell

this is my file:

```
$ cat sample1.txt
this is about weather. 
this is summer.   
I drink cold coffee 
I eat Ice-cream
I wear cotton clothes.
this is winter
I drink hot coffee
I eat cake
I wear warm clothes.
this is summer.
I wear cotton sleeveless.
I drink juice.
```

Now in this file If I found a word "summer", I need to update a word "cotton" to "light color", any inputs plz either with sed or awk.

Comment: The title and the description don't seem to be about the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

cotton.sh content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

summer=$(grep -Fo -m1 summer $1)
if [[ ${summer} == "summer" ]]; then
  sed -i 's/cotton/ligh color/g' $1
fi
```

Execute:

./cotton.sh sample1.txt

Remark: do not forget to set execution permission to your cotton.sh file script (chmod u+x cotton.sh)